# Python use regex to match characters for number, letter, space and brackets

Tags: python, regex

I know that to match only numbers letters and space, I can use:

```
re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$', word)
```

but I would like to also match brackets such as `()`, `{}`, `[]`. I extended the above regex to :

```
re.match(r'[A-Z][a-z][0-9][ ][(][)][{][}][[][]]]+$', word)
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas what the problem is? Or is there any concise regex guide that I can refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `r'[A-Z][a-z][0-9][ ][(][)][{][}][[][]]]+$'` matches a *sequence* of patterns defined:

- `[A-Z]` - uppercase ASCII letters
- `[a-z]` - lowercase ASCII letters
- `[0-9]` - ASCII digits
- `[ ]` - a space
- `[(]` - a `(`
- `[)]` - a `)`
- `[{]` - a `{`
- `[}]` - a `}`
- `[[]` - a `[`
- `[]]` - a `]`
- `]+` - one or more `]`s (as it is a standalone quantified atom).
- `$` - end of string.

It matches a string like [`Aa0 (){}[]]`](https://regex101.com/r/wE3xJ2/1)

You just need to add them to the character class:

```
re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9 (){}[\]]+$', word)
                      ^^^^^^^
```

Note that `(`, `)`, `{`, `}` and `[` do not require escaping inside the character class. The `]` does not have to be escaped when put at the character class start:

```
re.match(r'[][A-Za-z0-9 (){}]+$', word)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/KVYbb7)

Comment: FYI: In the IDEONE demo, you can see that `print(re.match(r'[][A-Za-z0-9 (){}]+$', "123[777]a(A)9 (more words)[here]]]]{{{0}}}"))` prints a match, thus, matching those symbols *anywhere* inside the string, not just in a specific order as in your expression.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clear, concise and easily understood !!

Answer (score 0):

In non-Java character classes, the only special characters are the escape `\`,
the dash `-`, the caret `^`, and the closing bracket `]`.

Of those -

- If the caret is not at the beginning, it's a literal,
  at the beginning, its a negation.
- If the dash is at the beginning or end it's a literal,
  in the middle, it's a range operator.
- If the closing bracket is at the beginning or right side of caret at the beginning,
  with no closing bracket following it somewhere, it is an unclosed class, an error.

By the time you figure this all out you're head will explode.

Save yourself from that and follow these simple rules:

Always escape literal brackets `[` and `]` no matter where they are.
Always escape literal dash `-` no matter where it is.
Always put a literal caret `^` on the right side of all other characters.

Nothing else needs to be escaped.

Examples:  `[a-z(){}\-\[\]^]` and `[^a-z(){}\-\[\]^]`